# simple stand alone way to generate .java file from .msg file

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple way to generate a .java file from a .msg file?

I don't want to use gradle/maven/cmake/catkin_make/rosmake etc

I already have an existing java application with a existing build/project files where I want to read data someone else is posting in a ROS topic. I can add the rosjava jar files easily enough but I don't have the .java file for specific custom message being published.

The tutorials seem to imply that I need to create a very complicated gradle/catkin project just to get the .java generated.
I tried following the tutorials but just get bogged down in a lot of problems that don't seem relevant to my real goal anyway.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100836/simple-stand-alone-way-to-generate-.java-file-from-.msg--file/) by [elkcahsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/8781/elkcahsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-14**:
What is your real goal? If you actually want to subscribe to a ROS topic from Java, then I'm afraid there is no easier way than creating a full-blown rosjava application.

**Comment by [elkcahsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/8781/elkcahsw/) on 2013-11-15**:
I think I made the "real goal" clear already.

I have an existing application that can read data from a number of possible data sources with different API's/protocols etc.
Only one provider of data wished to publish data using a ROS topic.
All of the other data providers had no trouble understanding that asking me to rebuild my application from scratch just to add their data source was completely unreasonable.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-15**:
No reason to get all excited, I'm just trying to help you out here - don't shoot the messenger. Maybe you find a way to accomplish what you want, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be good to get your feedback on where you got bogged down so we could improve the automated process rather than opting for a custom, manual approach.

If that is what you want to do, you can find the relevant details in the plugin code [here](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/blob/hydro/gradle_plugins/src/main/groovy/org/ros/gradle_plugins/CatkinPlugin.groovy#L147).

Essentially you are just executing java on the message_generation jar's org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces method.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0